# Countable intersection on an ultrafilter

Tags: set-theory, filters

Does there exist a nontrivial ultrafilter $a$ such that there are no sequence of sets $K_0,K_1,K_2\dots\in a$ such that $$K_0\cap K_1\cap K_2\dots = \emptyset?$$

Comment: See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/226609/8348).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In other words, a free ultrafilter which is closed under countable intersections.

It can be shown that if $\kappa$ is the least cardinal such that there is an ultrafilter as above on $\kappa$, then $\kappa$ is a **measurable cardinal**, and in fact the ultrafilter is closed under intersection of any less than $\kappa$ sets.

The consistency strength required to prove the existence of measurable cardinals exceeds that of $\sf ZFC$ by a long shot. In fact, the existence of measurable cardinals proves that $V\neq L$, where $L$ is Godel's constructible universe, in a very acute way. In particular there cannot exist a measurable cardinal in $L$ (or in a forcing extension thereof). So such ultrafilter as described above cannot be constructible (in the sense of Godel, that is).

Comment: The last sentence could use a retouch, don't you think? The existence of a real Cohen over $L$, or the assumption that $\mathsf{CH}$ fails, or ..., are all assertions that prove that $V\ne L$.

Comment: Andres, you're probably right. Thanks!

Comment: I must be missing something trivial. Why is it that no empty countable intersection implies closed under countable intersection?

Comment: @user21820: Can the *ultrafilter* contain the complement of the intersection?

Comment: That's what I can't see why not. It can't have the complement of any finite intersection, but why not the complement of the whole intersection?

Comment: @user21820: Suppose it did. Now take the countable intersection from before, and intersect it with the complement of said intersection. This is again a countable intersection of elements from the ultrafilter, but is it non-empty?

Comment: Lol! Okay I'm **dumbfounded**... Thanks a lot!